# Apply several constraints in one "validate" pass in Silex

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints, silex, explicit

I'm using Silex, and trying to validate some value with validator service. But the problem is that I need apply several constraints to one value, but validator don't let to do this without using `Required` constraint.

When I just want to validate a choice value (say, 'apple' or 'orange') I have to wrap constraints `Choice` and `NotNull` (because `Choice` allows a `null` value) into `Required` and `Collection` (because `Required` cannot be used without `Collection` and it is `CollectionValidator` who validates series of `Required`'s constraints) like this:

```
$violations = $app['validator']->validate(array('value'), 
    new Collection(array(
        new Required(array(
            new Choice(array('apple', 'orange')),
            new NotNull()
        ))
    )));
```

It looks verbose so I'm looking for more elegant solution (for such explicit use of validator).

Comment: Is the data in a form, or you're just validating some data standalone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `validateValue` function that accepts an array of constraints as second parameter.

```
$violations = $app['validator']->validateValue('value', array(
    new Choice(array('apple', 'orange')),
    new NotBlank()
));
```